# python asyncio await for first n task from list to complete

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I want to do async/await in python, and return once the first n task has been completed.
However, in asyncio it only has three options: ALL_COMPLETED, FIRST_COMPLETED, FIRST_EXCEPTION

What I am trying to do, is get to return when FIRST_N_COMPLETED.
So if I have 10 tasks in the task_list, and I want to wait for the first 3 to complete.

```
# task_list: list of asyncio.create_task()
done, pending = asyncio.wait(task_list)
```

`done` should have 3 completed tasks, and `pending` 7 uncomplete tasks

I tried creating another task with a while loop, that awaits the task_list and returns when FIRST_COMPLETED, and count up the completed task, then break when I reach 3 task. However I think it doesn't really work.

```
async def partialAwait(task_list, n=None):
    counter = 0
    total_tasks = len(task_list)
    if n is None or n > total_tasks:
        n = total_tasks

    while task_list and counter < n:
        done, task_list = await asyncio.await(task_list, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        counter += len(done)

    return task_list
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `as_completed()` might work for this?  Executing a `.cancel()` on the remaining tasks might be good housekeeping?

```
import time
from pprint import pprint
import asyncio
import random
import itertools
from time import perf_counter


async def worker(nap_time):
    print(f"Task {nap_time=} starting.")
    await asyncio.sleep(nap_time)
    return f"Task {nap_time=} done."


async def main():
    start_time = perf_counter()
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(worker(random.randint(1, 10))) for _ in range(10)]
    pprint([(t.get_name(), t._state) for t in tasks])

    for task in itertools.islice(asyncio.as_completed(tasks), 3):
        print(await task)

    for t in tasks:
        t.cancel()

    await asyncio.wait(tasks)
    pprint([(t.get_name(), t._state) for t in tasks])
    print(time.perf_counter() - start_time)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
[('Task-2', 'PENDING'),
 ('Task-3', 'PENDING'),
 ('Task-4', 'PENDING'),
 ('Task-5', 'PENDING'),
 ('Task-6', 'PENDING'),
 ('Task-7', 'PENDING'),
 ('Task-8', 'PENDING'),
 ('Task-9', 'PENDING'),
 ('Task-10', 'PENDING'),
 ('Task-11', 'PENDING')]

Task nap_time=7 starting.
Task nap_time=3 starting.
Task nap_time=1 starting.
Task nap_time=9 starting.
Task nap_time=4 starting.
Task nap_time=6 starting.
Task nap_time=4 starting.
Task nap_time=1 starting.
Task nap_time=3 starting.
Task nap_time=3 starting.

Task nap_time=1 done.
Task nap_time=1 done.
Task nap_time=3 done.

[('Task-2', 'CANCELLED'),
 ('Task-3', 'FINISHED'),
 ('Task-4', 'FINISHED'),
 ('Task-5', 'CANCELLED'),
 ('Task-6', 'CANCELLED'),
 ('Task-7', 'CANCELLED'),
 ('Task-8', 'CANCELLED'),
 ('Task-9', 'FINISHED'),
 ('Task-10', 'FINISHED'),
 ('Task-11', 'FINISHED')]

3.002996250000251
```

Comment: You could use `itertools.islice` to pull out the `n` tasks from `as_completed` without needing to explicitly maintain a count and test/break when it exceeds the limit.

Comment: This seems to work! Thanks a lot. Is it necessary to run `await asyncio.wait(tasks)`? For my use case, I wouldn't cancel the remaining tasks, and let it continue in the background.

Comment: The cancel/wait might be optional depending on your specific code/resource consumption.